# cmd > attrib - Unable to change attribute

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2003, file-attributes

I'm following this tutorial because I'm having problems with the Task Scheduler service:
http://technicallyeasy.net/2010/10/how-to-fix-keyset-does-not-exist-for-scheduled-tasks-in-windows/

Basically (in case the link dies), it says that you should go to C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18 and delete everything that's in there.

Here's the problem I'm having - there is a single file, marked as hidden, system and read-only.   The file name is "d42cc0c3858a58db2db37658219e6400_46884bcb-8fba-461e-a2ee-e996218ba78a".
When I try to delete it, I get the following message:
`Cannot delete X : Make sure you specifiy the correct path`

The file is definitely there, as I can browse to it via Windows Explorer.
I assumed that the problem is the "system" attribute.
I ran
`attrib -s "path\to\the\file"`

and the output:
`Unable to change attribute - "path\to\the\file"`

When I try to remove the hidden or read-only attributes instead, I get:
`Not resetting system file - "path\to\the\file"`

Once again, this is a **file**, not a folder.
Any ideas greatly appreciated!

PS: OS is Windows Server 2003 r2 x64

Comment: Did you try "attrib -s -h <file>" or "attrib -s -h -r <file>"? What is the output of "cacls <file>" (do you have enough rights on the file)?

Comment: "attrib -s -h <file>" or "attrib -s -h -r <file>" both produce the second error "Not resetting system file". I am certain that the account we're using has enough privileges to perform the operation. I have no idea what else may be wrong..

Comment: "I am certain that the account we're using has enough privileges to perform the operation." I am not. Therefore I asked for cacls output.

Comment: Have you tried LockHunter to delete the file? http://lockhunter.com/

Answer (score -1):

Attrib is giving me some problems today too. What I would try is `rd S-1-5-18 /s` from a command prompt in `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA`. Put the folder back if this works. There is the ["take ownership" option](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) - from the right click menu. Otherwise that file is in use and needs to be released by whatever `.exe` is using it. The path and file name don't exceed 256 so something is using it or windows is just mad at you.

Comment: Can you give more details about the file you linked to? While VirusTotal says it's not malware, bare links of this kind can be seen as suspicious.